# What is the right way to write SQLite DataBase Query to get User and pass form Users Table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have table for user info and need to get to user password and user user name
Query:

```
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select "+User.COL_NAME +User.COL_PASS +" from " + User.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+User.COL_NAME+ User.COL_PASS +"=?", new String[]{UserName , PassWord});
```

But I can't do that, the error message is:

```
   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: UserNamePassword (code 1): , while compiling: select UserNamePassword from users WHERE UserNamePassword=?
```

This is my code

```
public String getUserByUserAndPassword(String UserName , String PassWord) {


    String All_info="" ;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select "+User.COL_NAME +User.COL_PASS +" from " + User.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+User.COL_NAME+ User.COL_PASS +"=?", new String[]{UserName , PassWord});

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String user_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(User.COL_NAME));
        String pass_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(User.COL_PASS));
        All_info= user_1+"/"+pass_1;


    }
    cursor.close();
    return All_info ;}
```

Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: UserNamePassword (code 1):, while compiling: select UserNamePassword from users WHERE UserNamePassword=?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has syntax errors, but first I want to mention other parts of your code that are logically wrong.
Your query should return `0` or `1` row because I guess there is no case of 2 users with the same user name, right? 
So there is no need for a `while` loop. A simple `if` statement is enough.
Also why do you want the query to return the user name and password?
You already know them because you use them to search for this user.
If there is no user with these data then the query will not return anything.
So change your query to this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + User.TABLE_NAME +
    " WHERE "+ User.COL_NAME + " = ? AND " + User.COL_PASS +" = ?", 
    new String[]{UserName , PassWord}
);
```

This query will return only 1 row with 1 integer column with value `0` if there is no such user and `1` if there is.
And the rest of the code needed:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int counter = cursor.getInt(0);
    if (counter > 0) {
        All_info= UserName + "/" + PassWord;
    }
}
cursor.close();
return All_info;
```

Comment: i want to cheek if the user and password exist in database then for exsample i wnat to print Toast massge , i will try your code

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong, see the final query by print in console. Your code should be:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select "+User.COL_NAME +", "+User.COL_PASS +" from " + User.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+User.COL_NAME+"='"+UserName+"' AND "+ User.COL_PASS +"='"+PassWord+"'");
```

Comment: i was write it as "Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select "+User.COL_NAME +", "+User.COL_PASS +" from " + User.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+User.COL_NAME +"="+UserName+" AND "+User.COL_PASS +"="+PassWord , new String[]{UserName , PassWord});"  but ther is new error is (no such column: mas (code 1): , while compiling: select UserName, Password from users WHERE UserName=mas AND Password=123)

Comment: Oh my bad, you have to use `single qute` for `string value`. See the edited ans.

Answer (score 0):

You have written wrong query. This below query will work but why you are writing query for getting UserName and Password using UserName and Password itself so, either write the desired column_names OR just * for whole record in select statement.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select "+User.COL_NAME +", "+User.COL_PASS +" from " + User.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+User.COL_NAME+ "=?" + "and" + User.COL_PASS +"=?", new String[]{UserName , PassWord});
```

Comment: it is ok but it is not enter to while {} just enter to function